# Angular 2 Routing not working, no match

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am currently working on an Angular 2+ App which needs routing.
The whole color scheme of the app needs to change with the input of a URL parameter.

I am currently using this in my `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main/:key', component: MainComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
```

however when I visit:
`http://localhost:4200/main/someKey`
or
`http://localhost:4200/main?key=someKey`
the path can't be matched, The application is producing a 404.

This seems like the most basic application of URL parameters.
Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: Do you have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in place?

Comment: Yep I have it in my `app.component.html`

Comment: Can you create a https://stackblitz.com/ reproducing your problem.

Comment: Can you show us your MainComponent for context?

Comment: problem was the `<base href="/">`, was set to `./`. I changed it to `/` now it works

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing my base href. It was set to `<base href="./">`, because it wouldn't work when uploaded to a subdirectory on the server but for now I changed it back to `<base href="/">` which solved the url not matching.